# Get Dynamically Recipient Name in Email Body

Tags: conga

I have to unable to set Recipient Name from EmailToId in Conga Email Template.

[image]

Now, When I choose "To Address" then Its Name will display there.

Expected Result:
[image]

So, What I do for this?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the correct merge field format.  Open the Template Builder to find the correct merge field layout for the name.  I have a custom object called "MemberEnrollment__c" and the name merge field looks like this: Dear {{MEMBERENROLLMENT_EMPLOYEE_NAME}},